# How to install warp-cli in ubuntu container

Tags: ubuntu, cloudflare, cloudflare-argo

I'm trying to install Cloudflare warp-cli to ubuntu. Unfortunately I am not able to do it. https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/install

Here are my steps:

1. `docker run -it ubuntu bash`
2. `apt update`
3. `apt install curl gpg lsb-core -y`
4. `curl https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/pubkey.gpg | gpg --yes --dearmor --output /usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg`
5. `echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloudflare-warp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/ $(lsb_release -cs) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-client.list`
6. `apt update`
7. `apt install cloudflare-warp -y`

But when I run `warp-cli register` I'm getting `Error: "Unable to connect to CloudflareWARP daemon. Maybe the daemon is not running?"`

Hot to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `warp-svc` & (add & to run in the background). Only then can you run `warp-svc register`